# layout_below item inside included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to figure out a way to align an item in a layout in respect to an item within an included layout.
**Here's a visual representation:**
[image]

**And here is example code that I'm looking for (which obviously doesn't work):**
**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/info" />
    //This would be the dark grey box
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/item1">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**included.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm assuming the best way to accomplish this would be through dynamically positioning the dark grey box in code, but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: You'll not be able to do what you want(and from my point of view you wouldn't want to do it). Look at adding that extra window in code.

Comment: So this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450305/563735

Comment: So this solution has worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450305/563735

Comment: So this solution has worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450305/563735

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you make this below your include? Something like this (instead item1 use info):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/info" />
    //This would be the dark grey box
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/info">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I could, I guess. I originally wanted to have an arrow from the dark grey box point to the element inside the included layout. If I take your suggestion, I'd just have to remove the arrow and it would be sort of implied that it matched up with the box. I'm really looking for a method to align it to something inside an included layout though. The there will be several items inside the included element, and I would like the "popup" to align to whichever item is clicked. I updated the image to give a clearer idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think I've decided to go in this direction, so I'm accepting this answer :)