# Reference the id of a view inside an "include" layout in xml

Tags: android, xml

I have a button, `A`, inside `special_button.xml`, that I reuse on all my activities. Each activity has a root `RelativeLayout`.

The problem: one of my activities has a button, `B`, on the same position as `A`. I decided to just move `B` above `A`, but I can't reference `A` from the activity's xml.

Here are the xmls

**special_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

</merge>
```

**layout_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/special_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="<id to reference button A>"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `include` tag, you should also specify a new id within that XML, which you can then reference as the id within the `RelativeLayout`. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) and this sample code:

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag. For example:

```
<include android:id="@+id/news_title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     layout="@layout/title"/>
```

EDIT: As @eskimoapps.com points out, there appears to be a known issue doing this with `RelativeLayout`s, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316465/how-to-get-relativelayout-working-with-merge-and-include), but when I run the following code, it is working as OP requests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/special_button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_a_ref"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/A"     <!-- this still works, despite having warning in Eclipse -->
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the picture from HierarchyViewer showing the correct layout: `id/A` below `id/B`

[image]

My only thought is that Eclipse doesn't like it since it's statically trying to find the Button within the same layout file. Since `<include>` and `<merge>` work dynamically with the LayoutManager, that's probably while this still works as expected.

Please try and see if this works for you as well.

Comment: I have tried this. The problem with this approach is that the id is given to the root of the included layout. In my case, it is the `merge` tag, which is actually the `RelativeLayout` of the activity. I still have no access to button A.

Comment: Your statement is incorrect, if you give an id to the `<include>` that is not the same as the id for the `RelativeLayout`. Please check my edit and see if that helps.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I did not know that you could reference `A` directly. Just to let you know, I did not add  any data to the `<include>` tag, simply: `<include layout="@layout/special_button" />` and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know that the "id"(and other attributes) of include tag will override that of the root view on included layout. Your first paragraph opened my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` attribute to your `<include>` like this:

```
<include android:id="@+id/someId"
         layout="@layout/special_button"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this. The problem with this approach is that the id is given to the root of the included layout. In my case, it is the `merge` tag, which is actually the `RelativeLayout` of the activity. I still have no access to button A.

Comment: You will not be able to directly reference button A from the XML with this method, but you can now refer to the new ID that you define within the `<include>`. That will work in the `layout_above` value you mention.

Comment: This actually will not work if the merge tag is being used (id, visibility, and layout_* tags are ignored), and will also not work if layout_width and layout_height are not specified, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316465/how-to-get-relativelayout-working-with-merge-and-include

Comment: @anddev84: By using an id attached to the include, I will be referencing the `RelativeLayout` which covers the whole screen. I still do not have information on how I can place button B above button A.

Comment: @eskimoapps.com: Thank you for the link. Although Macarse's approach is more neat, I don't think it will solve my problem. I will try using alienjazzcat's approach.